Update from 22.04 to 24.04 has broken startup
Okay so I tried to upgrade from my 22.04 to 24.04. At some stage it asked me to reboot, and now I can't get in to my system. Note the below diagnostics were copied using Google Lens from photographs of my monitor so a small typo could be from that...
The error thrown was something like:
Gave up waiting for root file system device...
ALERT! UUID=4e2f2e69-e02c-4666-ae36-5c12c7f545d3 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!

It then gives me a (initramfs) prompt but it does not let me type here. Just a flashing cursor.
So then I tried installing 24.04 along side, which was probably a terrible idea and made things much worse... but here I am.
My grub looks like this:
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi)
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console)
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)
Advanced options for Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (24.04) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)
UEFI Firmware Settings

If I look at advanced options on /dev/nvme, I get these options:
Ubuntu (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-49-generic (on /dev/nvmeon1p2) 
Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-49-generic (recovery mode) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2) 
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1851-oem (on /dev/nvmeon1p2) 
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.14.0-1851-nem (recovery mode) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2) 
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi) (on /dev/nvme8n1p2) 
Memory test (memtest86+x64.efi, serial console) (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)

If I try any of the top 3, I get to the initramfs untypable prompt. If I try 5.14 it boots into a prompt and I can see all my existing files. If (from the original grub screen), I try and boot into the new Ubuntu 24.04, it works fine and I can mount my /dev/nvme0n1p2 and see all my old files including my old /etc/fstab which looks like this:
/etc/fstab: static file system information. 

Use 'bikid' to print the universally unique identifier for a device: this nay be used with UUID as a nore robust way to nane devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab (5). 

<file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
/ was on /dev/nvmen1p2 during installation 
UUID=4e2f2e69-e02c-4666-ae36-5c12c7f545d3 /              ext4     errors remount-ro 0 1 

/boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=A90E-1300 /boot/efi vfat umask-0077    0    1 
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0


blkid returns:
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="4e2f2e69-e02c-4666-ae36-5c12c7f545d3" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1e9a263d-ed7c-46a0-8794-b4e66401b8e2"

Running lsblk looks like:
loop0 to loop44 which are all /snap/...
loop43     7:43 0 346.8M 1 loop/snap/wine-platform-runtim 
loop44     7:44 0 346.8M 1 loop/snap/wine-platform-runtim 
sda        8:0 0931.5G O disk 
sda1       8:1 0 710.26 0 part 
sda2       8:2 0 16 0 part 
sda3       8:3 0 220.36 0 part 
sdb        8:16 1 OB O disk 
sro        11:0 1 1024M 0 rom 
nvme0n1   259:0    0 953.9G 0 disk 
nvme0η1p1 259:1    0 512M   0 part /boot/efi 
nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 953.4G 0 part /var/snap/firefox/common/h
                                   /

So it seems like I can see my nvme drive and it's all working fine. It just can't access it during boot up for some reason. Any ideas?
UPDATE
re-installing initramfs-tools has made it now bootable... Don't know why, but it works.
